# Opening links in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

[I have a very small Google Chrome Extension that uses Google Feed API to grab some data.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/illphpghffggnhciocgeobknfoclliim)

But the problem is visitors are not able to click on any links. I'd love to get some ideas about how to fix this. Basically any links within the popup.html are not openning in a new tab.

We have manifest.json, popup.html, and 3 icon files

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Gujarati Suvichar",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Gujarati Suvichar from GujaratiSuvichar.com",
  "icons": { "16": "gujarat - 16.jpg",
           "48": "gujarat - 48.jpg",
          "128": "gujarat - 128.jpg" },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "gujarat.jpg",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Here is the actual code from popup.html

```
<style>
body {
  min-width:350px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#footer {
    color: #F30;
}
#footer a{
    color: #F30;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyA5m1Nc8ws2BbmPRwKu5gFradvD_hgq6G0" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*
    *  How to use the Feed Control to grab, parse and display feeds.
    */

    google.load("feeds", "1");

    function OnLoad() {
      // Create a feed control
      var feedControl = new google.feeds.FeedControl();

      // Add two feeds.
      feedControl.addFeed("http://www.gujaratisuvichar.com/feed", "Gujarati Suvichar");

      // Draw it.
      feedControl.draw(document.getElementById("content"));
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    </script>

    <div id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>àª—à«àªœàª°àª¾àª¤à«€ àª¸à«àªµàª¿àªšàª¾àª°</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
<style>
.gf-result .gf-author, .gf-result .gf-spacer, .gf-result .gf-relativePublishedDate {
    display: none;
}
.gfc-result .gf-title a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#CCC
}
</style>    
    <div id="content">
    <div id="content">Loading...</div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    <span id="footer">More on <a href="http://www.gujaratisuvichar.com/">GujaratiSuvichar.com</a></span> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `<base target="_blank" />` into popup's `<head>`.

Comment: @Chirag Is it creating iframe inside that content div? Or dumping html right there?

Answer (score 1):

Your popup doesn't have a head. Or `<html>` tags. Make them.
Then add the 
    `<base target="_blank" />`
under your `<head>`